# Load array index from .txt file - separator

Tags: c++, file

im trying to load an array from .txt file and success with this code.

```
main(){
string nameArr[7];
ifstream file("name.txt");
if(file.is_open()){

    for(int i=0;i<7;++i){
        file >> nameArr[i];
    }   
}

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    cout << nameArr[i] << endl;
}
}
```

And with this .txt file.

> Bosko Alphard Galih Reh Adit Dita Dani

So, the question is.. if i have long string format with space how should i do with the .txt file (what separator should i use) and how should i write the code?

Comment: Use a `vector` and keep reading until eof.

Comment: If the strings are on separate lines, use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Your question is not clear. make it more clear also show a sample of your txt file. and clear what actually you want to do ?

Comment: how should i write on the code? if i use getline.

Comment: My question is, how should i do when i have long string format with space and other character - what separator should i use on .txt file.
and what should i write in the code.

Comment: @AchmadSyaifudin you can see my answer example on your 7 lines in your txt contains spaces or any type of character. if you can give me a txt file example what do you want i can make it more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getline()` syntax like this, if you want your whole line in one string.

```
main(){
string nameArr[7];
ifstream file("name.txt");
if(file.is_open()){

    for(int i=0;i<7;++i){
        getline(file,filenameArr[i]) //if you want to take a full line in a string // this will take 7 lines from your txt
    }   
}

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    cout << nameArr[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i mean.

Comment: can u show me how to put full string with space  and put it in the new line of the .txt file?

Comment: You mean getting input from user with spaces and put it in file with spaces and new line ?

Comment: Yes! you should write it.